# Elasticsearch not working when open network to remote

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to change my elasticsearch.yaml to remote access.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

after doing that I make

```
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

and it returns error.

```
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

in the journalctl -xe is:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch.
bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_provide
 ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
 elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

When `network.host` is set to localhost, your cluster is in development mode. As soon as you set it to 0.0.0.0, you cluster transitions to production mode and there are some [bootstrap checks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html) that need to be satisfied in order for the cluster to start.

One of those checks concerns the [discovery configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_discovery_configuration_check.html) of the cluster/nodes.

In production mode, the first time you start your cluster needs to be [bootstrapped](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html), which means you need to set one of the following settings:

- `discovery.seed_hosts`
- `discovery.seed_providers`
- `cluster.initial_master_nodes`

which is what the error message is saying:

> the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_provide

Answer (score 3):

After setting

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Elastic opinionated code, thinks you are in production now and mandates that cluster settings are needed.

In general, when I am just learning something new like elastic search, I will stand up a host with the software on it to experiment. Not my everyday computer that I use to browse the web, check emails, etc. That experimental host can be wiped when I am done. So opening a single node to the network should not be considered production in my case. It's an experimental single node server not on the internet. If you are trying to do the same, just do this:
Edit elasticsearch.yml and find the commented out line cluster.initial_master_nodes. Change

```
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
```

to have the IP address of the computer that is running elastic.

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["192.168.0.105"]
```

Note the non-internet addressable IP for my experimental host, here today, gone tomorrow. This experimental host will always be given the same IP address by my network router, so no worries after reboot. This also worked for me.

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["127.0.0.1"]
```